# Message Passing is not working in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I am try to messaging passing from my Default_popup.js to content script and when it's receive at content script end then try to save data on chrome storage. but my code is not working properly.

This code was worked 2-3 times. but now it's not working.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Automated Test Tool.",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "Default_Popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js":["myscript.js"]    }
    ],
    "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions":[
        "storage",
         "notifications",
         "tabs",
         "http://*/",
         "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

Popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    var Jour = {};
    Jour.FromStation = $('#txtFromStation').val();
    Jour.ToStation = $('#txtToStation').val();
    Jour.JourneyDate = $('#datepicker').val();
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { JourneyDetails: Jour }, function handler(response) {
        alert("Inside Client = " + "Done");
    });
});
```

myscript.js  //Content Script

```
window.onload = function () {

    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            alert('request.JourneyDetails.FromStation');
            alert(request.JourneyDetails.FromStation);
            var Jour = {};
            Jour.FromStation = request.FromStation;
            Jour.ToStation = request.ToStation;
            Jour.JourneyDate = request.JourneyDate;
            chrome.storage.sync.set({ JourneyDetails: Jour }, function () {
                console.log('Setting Saved')
            });
            //sendResponse({ counter2: "5" });      
       }
    );
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Answer (score 1):

1. `chrome.tabs.getSelected()` is deprecated, try using `chrome.tabs.query()` instead? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected
2. `chrome.tabs.sendRequest()` and `chrome.extension.onRequest()` are deprecated, try using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage()` instead? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendRequest, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest
3. Do you include jQuery in Default_Popup.html? What are the errors you are seeing?
4. Are the elements with ids `$('#txtFromStation'), $('#txtToStation'), $('#datepicker')` in Default_Popup.html? If you could post the content of Default_Popup.html that will be helpful.